# HyperTable - Why we can't use the * in Select Clause?

Tags: select, clause, hypertable

Ok
I have some trouble getting through [HyperTable](http://hypertable.com)
Going through the docs and other stuff I am still not very confident at why I can't use the

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE....
```

I am allowed only to do

```
SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE WHERE COL_NAME = COL_VAL;
```

What if I want to select two columns using a rowkey? Does this mean I am wont be allowed?
Or have I not understood something that is important? Look like the latter to me.

> Using Hypertable for windows
>
> hypertable> select Col_Id1,Col_Id2 from test where Col_Id2 ="131600";

I get the following

> Error: Hypertable::Exception: Column predicate name not identical with
>   selected column - HYPERTABLE HQL parse error
>           at Hypertable::Hql::scan_set_column_predicate_name::operator () (c:\soft
>   dev\devel\hypertable\ht4w\src\cc\hypertable\lib\HqlParser.h:825) -
>   HYPERTABLE HQ L parse error

This works as docs state.

```
select Col_Id2 from test where Col_Id2 ="131600";
```

Any help and guidance appreciated.

Thanks.

Wajih

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROW = "rowkey";

type "help select" in the shell to get a full list of options and examples.

Comment: the row key is the "primary index". if you want to search by values then you can use "... WHERE VALUE REGEXP 'blah'" or "... WHERE column = 'blah'"; the latter only works in 0.9.5.6. Searching by value is slow unless you create a secondary index. See this blog post for more information: 
http://www.hypertable.com/blog/secondary_indices_have_arrived/